# Dropzone.js with Rails 4: "Template is missing" error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm trying to use Dropzone.js with Rails 4, and although I can get the actual Dropzone 'zone' to appear, when I try to upload images, the following

```
Template is missing Missing template projects/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en],           :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}
```

However, I'm quite sure that I have the template, as images that are being uploaded without Dropzone are uploading and displaying fine

My code is as follows:

ProjectImagesController:

```
class ProjectImagesController < ApplicationController

    def create 
        @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        @project_image = @project.project_images.create(project_image_params)
        redirect_to project_path(@project)
    end

    private

    def project_image_params
        params.require(:project_image).permit(:caption, :image)
    end
end
```

projects/show.html.erb

```
<% if @project.project_images.any? %>
<% @project.project_images.each do |project_image|%>
<ul>
    <li><%= image_tag project_image.image.url(:thumb) %></li>
    <li><%= project_image.caption %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_image], :html => {:multipart => true, class: :dropzone} do |f| %>
<div>
<%= f.input :caption, label: 'Enter your project image caption' %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.submit 'Create project image'%>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dropzone sends request in **JSON format**, but you try to render **HTML**, so you have to change your controller:

from

```
def create 
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @project_image = @project.project_images.create(project_image_params)
  redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

to

```
def create 
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @project_image = @project.project_images.create(project_image_params)

  render nothing: true
end
```

or something else in JSON format

hope I'll help somebody...